# Protractor check if element has children

Tags: javascript, webdriver, protractor

I have a click event where child elements get appended to a parent element and then get removed on another click event. I want to test if those elements got removed from the parent. So is there something like

```
var container = element(by.css('.container'));
expect(container.length).toEqual(0);
```

that checks if there are any children elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are special methods for checking if an element is present:

```
elm.isPresent();
parentElm.isElementPresent(childElm);  
browser.isElementPresent(elm);
```

And here are the differences between them:

- [In protractor, browser.isElementPresent vs element.isPresent vs element.isElementPresent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33019429/in-protractor-browser-iselementpresent-vs-element-ispresent-vs-element-iselemen)

---

Note that you can still find all elements inside a container and check the count:

```
var container = element(by.css('.container'));
expect(container.all(by.xpath("./*")).count()).toEqual(0);
```

Another alternative could be to check the inner HTML:

```
expect(container.getInnerHTML()).toEqual("");
```