# How do I test a non-angular site with protractor js?

Tags: javascript, protractor, e2e-testing

I've been looking all around the internet but there doesn't seem to be any reliable resources or examples that test non-angular websites with protractor JS.

Currently, my conf file looks like this

```
 exports.config = {
  seleniumServerJar: 'webdriver/selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar',
  specs: [
    'wikipedia-test-spec.js'
  ], 
  chromeDriver : 'webdriver/chromedriver.exe',

  multiCapabilities: [
    {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    }
  ],

  };
```

And my wikipedia-test-spec.js looks like this

```
describe("Tests a wikipedia page", function(){
     it('Should check if table exists', function(){
            browser.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_dependencies_by_population');
            var table = browser.driver.findElement(by.name('table'));
            expect(table.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
    });

});
```

When I run `protractor conf.js`, I get a type error `undefined is not a function` and my spec fails.

UPDATE:

Entire stack trace of the error

```
 Stacktrace:
     TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\nodejs\CGAngularTest\wikipedia-test-spec.js:5:26)
    at C:\Users\jayarajp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd\index.js:94:14
    at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\Users\jayarajp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:130:15)
From: Task: Asynchronous test function: it()
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\jayarajp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd\index.js:93:33)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\jayarajp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\async-callback.js:45:37)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Block.execute (C:\Users\jayarajp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:1174:17)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.next_ (C:\Users\jayarajp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2209:31)
    at [object Object]._onTimeout (C:\Users\jayarajp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2199:18)
Error
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\nodejs\CGAngularTest\wikipedia-test-spec.js:2:3)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe_ (C:\Users\jayarajp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:913:21)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe (C:\Users\jayarajp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:898:15)
    at describe (C:\Users\jayarajp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:658:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\nodejs\CGAngularTest\wikipedia-test-spec.js:1:63)
```

Comment: Please post the complete error traceback.

Comment: Updated the question with full stack trace of the error

Comment: I wouldn't try to use Protractor w/a non Angular site. Protractor is a souped up version of Selenium / Selenium Web Driver that knows how Angular works. Use Selenium instead :)

Comment: @SunilD. protractor can and I would even say should (cause of all the syntactic sugar and utils) be definitely used for non-angular sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`isPresent()` function](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/d7bb003062077833c491820ec39cf73592bc6c13/lib/element.js#L908) is available on the `ElementFinder` instance, which is the result of `element()` call. You might need to use `driver.isElementPresent()` here:

```
var table = browser.driver.findElement(by.name('table'));
expect(table.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
```

with:

```
var table = browser.driver.findElement(by.name('table'));
expect(browser.driver.isElementPresent(table)).toBeTruthy();
```

Or, you can also try with `element()`:

```
var table = element(by.name('table'));
expect(table.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
```

---

Note that you would also need to *turn the synchronization with AngularJS off*:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
```

Also see:

- [In protractor, browser.isElementPresent vs element.isPresent vs element.isElementPresent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33019429/in-protractor-browser-iselementpresent-vs-element-ispresent-vs-element-iselemen)

Comment: Where do I put `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` ?

Comment: @DivyanthJayaraj you can have it in your test, but a better place would be `onPrepare()` in your protractor config.