# Looking for an element to not be present

Tags: automation, webdriver, protractor

I'm trying to look for an absence of an element in a conditional which would then take two different paths if the element is not there.  However what I am getting is 'element not found' which is what I need but I need to go around this. Here is what I've tried:

```js
if (HomeScreen.tabs.propertiesTab.isPresent()) {
  HomeScreen.tabs.propertiesTab.click();
} else {
  HomeScreen.tabs.allTabsTab.click().then(function() {
    HomeScreen.allTabs.properties.click();
  })
}
```

and

```js
HomeScreen.tabs.propertiesTab.isPresent().toBeFalsy().then(function(isVisible) {
  if (isVisible) {
    HomeScreen.tabs.propertiesTab.click();
  } else {
    HomeScreen.tabs.allTabsTab.click().then(function() {
      HomeScreen.allTabs.properties.click();
    });

  }
});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to explicitly resolve the promise with `then()`:

```
browser.isElementPresent(HomeScreen.tabs.propertiesTab).then(function (isPresent) {
    if (isPresent) {
        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Using `browser.isElementPresent()` here, but it should work with `.isPresent()` as well:

- [In protractor, browser.isElementPresent vs element.isPresent vs element.isElementPresent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33019429/in-protractor-browser-iselementpresent-vs-element-ispresent-vs-element-iselemen)

Comment: This work however the element is present as I can see it and if I comment everything out and tell it to click it will click on it.  I did a log of isPresent and it returns false.

Comment: @NicolePhillips okay, are you sure you are locating the element correctly and there are no other elements matching the locator?

Comment: Perhaps what I need is visibility of?

Comment: @NicolePhillips if you need a wait, then probably - meaning, if the element is actually present, but not visible you might need `visibilityOf` or `invisibilityOf`. For presence/absence checks you can use `stalenessOf` or `presenceOf`.